# Does calling a method from within a method with a lock maintain exclusive access to memory?

Tags: c, pthreads, locking, mutex

I'm  basically asking if I acquire a lock in one method and call a second method from that method, will the second one maintain exclusive memory access?
Here is some example code. For reference, I'm coding in C using pthreads.

```
int count = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

method1() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    count++;
    method2();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

method2() {
    printf("count = %d\n", count);
}
```

So if thread A starts and calls method1 (acquiring the lock), would A's call of method2 within method1 still be memory locked since A still has the mutex lock? So no other threads could change count while A is still printing it?

Comment: Short answer is yes. But if some other thread accesses   Method2 then there won't be any lock.

Comment: @MKR so what is the point of a lock? `method2` is a *read* process anyway.

Comment: If you're asking about the mutex lock, yes, the mutex will remain locked until the locking thread calls `pthread_mutex_unlock` on it. However, that's not the same question as _"So no other other threads could change `count` while A is still printing it?"_ That's entirely up to the design of your code. Thread synchronization doesn't happen by magic just because you use a mutex. If you're telling another thread to modify `count` without thread synch then you will have race conditions.

Comment: _[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/261690/645128)_ to a question about thread safety in general might also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

No, `method2` is not exclusive due to `method1` taking the mutex. All other threads may call and get access to `method2` - regardless of the mutex state.

No other thread can access `method1` but `method2` is available for all threads.

Therefore thread X can call `method2` while thread Y executes `method1` which may cause thread X to print some incomplete value.

If you want to protect `method2`, you must move the mutex into it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the access of `method2()` to `count` is protected by the mutex *when `method2()` is called from `method1()`*. But that *doesn't* apply if `method2()` was called from another place, without the mutex held.